# Creating match rooms with firebase

Tags: firebase

Im building a game where some k number of people can play, live

Im using firebase for sharing user-related data and obtaining updates from a backend nodeJS on heroku. So far so good, but I have one major requirement that I havent yet fully figured out to build using firebase and a NodeJS backend

There could be potentially a large number of users wanting a play a game. I'd like to match k of these users and assign them a unique gameroom id, where they can then 'play' . For the sake of this question we can omit what the actual 'play' is.

So I'd like to create a random set of k users and here is how Im thinking of approaching it, I'd like to know if this is a good approach or a terrible approach. I'd also like more suggestions if there is an easier way to achieve this:

1. Live players indicate on my Firebase store that they'd like to play
   using a state variable
2. A NodeJS backend on Heroku runs every few seconds to ensure that the system
   has a good 'mix' of players. When it runs, it uses the [Firebase REST
   API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/) to pull up *all* the waiting Live players (is this a good idea?)
3. It then sections off these live players to a [Firebase Queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue). It does
   this by taking 1000*k live users and creating 1 task. Thus it may
   create many such tasks with 1000*k users in each task.

I'd like to add that if there was a way for a single queue worker to access multiple tasks then I would much prefer that. In that case Step 2 is pretty much not required, since the live players can add themselves to the queue and a single worker can access k of these users to match them together - is this possible with the current Firebase Queue??

4. Queue workers pick up a task and make 1000 matches and write these
   match details in the players node in firebase
5. Players waiting on their node are now matched with a unique gameroom
   id and k other players

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/u28mc3shvjY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying this is a conceptual answer and doesn't directly involve Firebase queues. Those could be leveraged accordingly.

We don't know what the criteria is to create a good mix of players but let me give it a shot using a typical Warcraft dungeon group. That group will have 5 players; a tank (leader) a healer and three players that deal damage (dps)

In this example, it seems that the solution could be presented by observing the changes in each game_room node, and also watching the waiting_players node for changes as well.

Example structure:

```
game_room_0   
  current_players
       player_0
         type: tank
       player_1
         type: healer
       player_3
         type: dps
       player_4
         type: dps
       player_5
         type: dps

waiting_players
       player_6
         type: dps
       player_7
         type: healer
```

There would be x number of game_rooms, each needing 5 players.

The app observes the current_players node (in each game_room) for removed players.

It will also be observing the waiting_players node for added players

When a player leaves from a game_room/current_players node, player_0 for example, the tank (oh no!) your app will be notified of that change and can then query the waiting_players node for type = tank.

At that point it will have a list of the waiting tanks and could randomly select one or further narrow down the criteria for a better mix. Then add it to the game_room that needed a tank.

In this case, there are no tanks waiting, but the app is observing that node so when a new player is added to the waiting_players node (a player indicates that he wants to play), the app is notified of that added player, and if it's a tank, they can be placed into a game_room to replace the one that left.

This approach would avoid having to load in all the waiting players as the app will know which specific ones are needed. It would also take the load off the app to have 1000 * k tasks as the app is relying on Firebase events.

Finally, it can respond to players leaving or being added to avoid polling and even reducing the dependency on Firebase Queue

If this is way off the mark, let me know.

Comment: Hi Jay, I like your answer a lot because its giving me new ways to think :D . Now, lets say the game was an arcade-style race. Assume that the race begins at the same time and the race-play mechanics are handled. Gamerooms are where races take place. Now 5 players race together at random. When the race begins and a player leaves midway, that player is disqualified and the race continues for the remainder players. Can you provide your thoughts on effectively matching race players and creating races using this analogy?

Comment: That's a pretty big question: are we to assume that all racers are equivalent? i.e. they all have the same model car/bike/tricycle that have the same specs? If so, then is it first-come first served? i.e. gameroom_0 is empty, and player0 signs up, He is put into the room0 race, then player1 signs up and he is added. rinse, repeat until all 5 slots are filled in room0. Then they race. The next person that signs up is put into room1, then the next is added to room1. Etc etc. then room1 races. Or do you want to match racers by some qualifications? This may go beyond the scope of Stackoverflow.

Comment: All racers are equivalent. They are matched with no qualifications (completely random). I'd like the system to wait until it has a decent amount of waiting players so its not necessarily first-come first served. You are right - this can get beyond SO's scope - is there a better way to discuss this?